# Why does Tkinter stops working after any import?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have such weird problem with python tkinter
code of graphick_tutorials.text_display.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
# TOFO - ok, there is a bug:
import graphick_tutorials.dummy as dd

class GameDisplayer():
    def __init__(self, gc):
#
        self.gc = gc
        self.root = tk.Tk()#
        self.label = tk.Label(text="000")        
        self.label.pack()        
        self.counter = 0
        self.update_clock()
        self.root.mainloop()

        

    def update_clock(self):
        self.counter +=1
        self.label.configure(text=str(self.counter))
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_clock)
        
gd =GameDisplayer(0)
```

this code stops working after ANY import for example, just:
code of graphick_tutorials.dummy.py:

```
class Dummy:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Makes the error in label and it shows without text, while
commenting out the import makes the counter work fine, what can be an issue here please?

Comment: Works OK when I try it using your `Dummy` class — so must have something to do with what's in your real `graphick_tutorials.dummy` module.

Comment: Are you saying _this exact code_ exhibits this problem?when you say “makes the error”, what is the error?

Comment: it has shown empty and wrong sized label. The strange problem was realy caused by wrong import "graphick_tutorials.dummy " location, i must "import dummy " in this project, but strangely it was run without proper error